# How to join Objects in Django with Foreign Keys 2 tables deep

Tags: django, join, orm

I have 2 models each with foreign keys to 2 tables.  I'm trying to join the 1st table to the 3rd.
Here are my models:

Model 1:

```
class AppBillingBil(models.Model):
    id_bil = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    idtrp_bil = models.ForeignKey(AppTradingPartnerTrp, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idtrp_bil', blank=True,
                                  null=True)
    idcst_bil = models.ForeignKey(AppCustomerCst, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idcst_bil')
    idbtp_bil = models.ForeignKey(AppBillingTypeBtp, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idbtp_bil')



    class Meta:
        db_table = 'app_billing_bil'
        ordering = ['id_bil']
```

Model 2:

```
class AppCustomerCst(models.Model):
    id_cst = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    is_active_cst = models.BooleanField()
    name_cst = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

Model 2:

```
class AppTradingPartnerTrp(models.Model):
    id_trp = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tpid_trp = models.CharField('TPID', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    name_trp = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50)
```

Final Model Needed:

```
class AppCustomerTpRel(models.Model):
    id_rel = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    idcst_rel = models.ForeignKey(AppCustomerCst, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idcst_rel')
    idtrp_rel = models.ForeignKey(AppTradingPartnerTrp, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='idtrp_rel')
    cust_vendor_rel = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

I need to join on the following criteria:
`idtrp_bil__id_trp = idtrp_rel`
`idcst_bil__id_cst = idcst_rel`

And I need to be able to use the `cust_vendor_rel` field from `AppCustomerTpRel` in a filter query on `AppBillingBil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships  I tried this, and was successful:

`idcst_bil__appcustomertprel__cust_vendor_rel`

I realized I needed to include the target model name in the value grab.